# How to work with CF hash

Tags: c++, c, hash, coldfusion

My web app was written in CF8. The programmer who wrote the original program has long been gone & left me with no documentation at all.
I see a problem when I need to work on the login action page where previous programmer did not use CF to process the incoming password but used an executable in C/C++.  User’s password is passed to this executable and this program will hashed users password using MD5 algorithm as far as I can tell.

To make it more complicated, this hashed password match with the hashed passwords stored in the DB used by a dot net web app. The dot net app. is our main web app., the CF8 app is a complementary app to the dot net one. Our users use these two apps. Interchangeably using the same username and password.

I’m given a task to convert CF8 app. (installed in Solaris), to CF10 (in a new Linux server) and the C/C++ executable is no longer work with Linux. In other words, I can’t use this executable to hashed user passwords anymore. Since I don’t have enough knowledge to convert and manipulate C/C++ program, I plan to create similar functionality in CF10. 
My question is, what do I need to do in CF10 so my program will be able to generate the same hashed passwords that is created by the dot net web app (stored in the DB).

I did the following but mine returned a different hashed password. This password can’t be used to login to any of my two web app because the hashed password doesn’t match the one stored in DB.

```
<cfset password = "#Trim(MyPWD)#" /> 
<cfset crypto = createObject("component", "cfcomponents.md5_crypto") /> 
<cfset salt = crypto.genSalt() /> 

<cfset X = crypto.CHash(password,salt) /> 

  <cfdump var="#Trim(X)#"> <!--- I got a different hasked password ---> 


      <!--- My component: md5_crypto.cfc --->
      <cfcomponent displayname="CF10_PWdHash">

      <cffunction name="CHash" access="public" returntype="String">
      <cfargument name="password" type="string" />
      <cfargument name="salt" type="string" />
      <cfargument name="iterations" type="numeric" required="false" default="16" />
      <cfargument name="algorithm" type="string" required="false" default="MD5" />

      <cfscript>

        var hashed = '';
        var i = 1;
        hashed = hash( password & salt, arguments.algorithm, 'UTF-8' );
        for (i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) {
          hashed = hash( hashed & salt, arguments.algorithm, 'UTF-8' );
        }

        return hashed;

      </cfscript>

       </cffunction>

           <cffunction name="genSalt" access="public" returnType="string">
       <cfargument name="size" type="numeric" required="false" default="16" />      
            <cfscript>          
            var byteType = createObject('java', 'java.lang.Byte').TYPE;
            var bytes = createObject('java','java.lang.reflect.Array').newInstance( 
                                                                               byteType , size);
            var rand = createObject('java', 'java.security.SecureRandom').nextBytes
                    (bytes);

            return toBase64(bytes);      
        </cfscript>

        </cffunction>   
            </cfcomponent)
```

I see the C/C++ program has the following codes:

```
      #include "md5.h"
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <string.h>

      #define SALT "J@kaR@ta"

     /*
      * Purpose: this routine calculates and md5 hash based on the first
      * argument passed returns the first 15 hex characters
      * of that hash     
      */

      void main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
      {
         char pass_and_salt[256];
         char password_hash[256];
         char connect_string[256];

         sprintf(pass_and_salt, "%s%s", argv[1], SALT);
         encryptMD5(pass_and_salt, password_hash);

         //fprintf(stderr, "hash=%s\r\n", password_hash);
         fflush(stderr);

         printf("%s\n", password_hash);
         }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Regardless of the program or method you use to hash your passwords, you have to know the algorithm. You said it *might* be MD5, but without knowing for sure, how can you expect to make this work?

Comment: Since Solaris and Linux is not that much different, have you tried to just recompile the C++ source on the Linux system? The usual worst case you might have to change some `#include` directives, and maybe some linker libraries.

Comment: Definitely agree on re-compiling what looks like a very simple C++ script in Linux as being the simple solution. However, I hope that once you have existing logins working, you will be looking at porting everyone across to an algorithm that is actually secure - MD5 is broken and not suitable for cryptographic use.

Comment: I have no documentation at all so I can't say with 100% that I'm sure it is NOT MD5. Looking at the C/C++ codes, the word MD5 is used everywhere. Such as the one I posted here, #include "md5.h",encryptMD5, why would someone used MD5 had the algorithm is not an MD5, seriously?. Have tried to compiled it in linux and it was unseccessfull despite of trying it for weeks.